# Getting AWS parameters with AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, aws-sdk

I have set up a parameter in my parameter store using my default account, and have tested I can retrieve it via the AWS CLI with the command:

> aws ssm get-parameter --name "/Test/TestParam1"

and also using my region, just in case that was an issue:

> aws ssm get-parameter --name "/Test/TestParam1" --region eu-west-1

Now i have created a .net core console app with a reference to the AWS SDK and am trying to retrieve the param via the **AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient**, with the following code :

```cs
static async Task GetParameterStore()
{

    var region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;

    var request = new GetParameterRequest()
    {
        WithDecryption = false,
        Name = "/Test/TestParam1"
    };

    using (var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(region))
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetParameterAsync(request);
            var value = response.Parameter.Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"Parameter {request.Name} has value: {response.Parameter.Value}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

However I keep getting the error:

> User X is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource:
> x::parameter/Test/TestParam1  with explicit deny.

I have verified the user mentioned in the error is that of my default account from my credentials file and the same one who created the param in the param store.

Is there any extra level of access or policy I need to create for my account to get access via the AWS SDK here, that differs from what is needed when using the AWS ssm get-parameter from the command line? Or am I doing something else wrong here?